# Making an add-in ribbon button do something

Tags: vb.net, callback, outlook, ribbon

I have been following the tutorial for adding the add-ins ribbon to Outlook.  In my project I have MyRibbon.vb and MyRibbon.xml.  I have edited MyRibbon.xml so there is a button that says "Green Print".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="MyGroup"
               label="My Group">
          <button id="printButton" label="Green Print" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

In MyRibbon.vb I have added some code which I was hoping would display a message saying "Hello World" when the button is clicked:

```
#Region "Ribbon Callbacks"
    'Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=271226
    Public Sub Ribbon_Load(ByVal ribbonUI As Office.IRibbonUI)
        Me.ribbon = ribbonUI
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnActionCallback(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl,
        ByVal isPressed As Boolean)

        If (control.Id = "printButton") Then
            MsgBox("Hello World!")
        End If

    End Sub

#End Region
```

However when I click on the Green Print button in the add-ins ribbon nothing happens - no error message or anything just nothing.  Where am I going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the pointer to the callback in your XML.  Use:

```
<button id="printButton" label="Green Print" onAction="OnActionCallback"/>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this.  I also found that I had to remove the line:
ByVal isPressed As Boolean